# Getting error while trying to run the ruby script in osx yosemite

Tags: ruby, rspec, osx-yosemite

```
$ rspec auth.rb
-bash: /usr/local/bin/rspec: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Why do I get the above error?

Additional infos:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

LOCAL GEMS

```
$ gem list
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
childprocess (0.5.6)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
ffi (1.9.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rspec (3.3.0)
rspec-core (3.3.2)
rspec-expectations (3.3.1)
rspec-mocks (3.3.2)
rspec-support (3.3.0)
rubygems-update (2.4.8)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
selenium-webdriver (2.48.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
websocket (1.2.2)
```

Used this command to open the script

```
sudo nano auth.rb
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: How does you script look like - especially does it start with a [Shebang](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang)?

Comment: It lookis like following:
#!/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8
require "json"
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
include RSpec::Expectations

Comment: Does `/bin/env` exist on your system? On my machine it needs to be: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

Comment: I think NO. I am very bad in command line and started using MAC
Between How do i chk that?
How do i modify if needed?

Does the following means something to you?
bash: /usr/local/bin/rspec: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby: bad interpreter

Comment: Did you try to change it to this `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in your script?

Comment: Actually, i exported the ruby script from selenium IDE at work where i use windows and copied the script in textedit in mac at my home.

Comment: Your script should not be added as a comment, instead add it to your question as if you had added it initially. Don't add any "Edit" or "Update" header or comment. And format the code for readability. See [ask].

Comment: `sudo nano...`? Until you understand what `sudo` does and why you should use it, I'd strongly recommend NOT using it. Instead, please learn about using an operating system, especially Mac OS, at the command-line. Your computer will thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
https://books.google.fr/books?id=_0YaSjsLDvkC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=ruby+script+from+windows+to+mac&source=bl&ots=sNyriyzF1U&sig=UEB7NhYzhLoNqw7PjZMMGgQO4dg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMI0PD4sK3EyAIVgbQaCh1noQTg#v=onepage&q=ruby%20script%20from%20windows%20to%20mac&f=false

It is seen that To run the ruby scripts on mac OSX, the following command can be included as the first statement in the rubyscript.

## !/usr/bin/ruby -w

Comment: `-w` just turns on warnings. Try `ruby -h` at the command-line. It doesn't change any other behaviors and isn't necessary to run a script on Mac OS..beyond that you are only recommending a normal `#!` line.

Comment: @theTinMan what does ruby -h do?